# Run corflags automaticly after build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, corflags

I build a WPF program for the .NET framework. I need to run the following corflags command in order for the program to work correctly.

```
corflags c:/[file location]/[file name].exe /32BITREQ+
```

Now I do this manually trough the visual studio console, but I would like to do that automaticly after a build completed. Is that possible?

I tried to search around for a solution but couldn't find one. My best guess is to use a command in the Post-build event command line. I tried to following.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\corflags.exe" "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\QardPrint.exe" /32BITREQ+
```

This gives the following error. in the Output window.

```
1>Target "PostBuildEvent: (TargetId:81)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "H:\VSWorkspace\VSTS\Quantore\LoginQard\QardPrint\QardPrint.csproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
1>Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Exec" (TaskId:58)
1>  Task Parameter:WorkingDirectory=bin\x86\Debug\ (TaskId:58)
1>  Task Parameter:Command="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\corflags.exe" "H:\VSWorkspace\VSTS\Quantore\LoginQard\QardPrint\bin\Debug\QardPrint.exe" /32BITREQ+ (TaskId:58)
1>  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\corflags.exe" "H:\VSWorkspace\VSTS\Quantore\LoginQard\QardPrint\bin\Debug\QardPrint.exe" /32BITREQ+ (TaskId:58)
1>  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags Conversion Tool.  Version  4.6.1055.0 (TaskId:58)
1>  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. (TaskId:58)
1>   (TaskId:58)
1>corflags : error CF001: Could not open file for writing
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5019,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\corflags.exe" "H:\VSWorkspace\VSTS\Quantore\LoginQard\QardPrint\bin\Debug\QardPrint.exe" /32BITREQ+" exited with code 1.
1>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:58)
```

In the error list

```
Could not open file for writing QardPrint   H:\VSWorkspace\VSTS\Quantore\LoginQard\QardPrint\corflags
```

---

Instead of using corflags directly I also tried the following things Hans Passant suggested in the comments.

- ProjectProperties-->Build-->General-->PlatformTarget: x86
- ProjectProperties-->Build-->Platform: x86

This did not solve the error I have with an oracle connection (version 9.2). My manual corflags command does solve this issue.

Comment: You didn't set the PATH so corflags.exe can be found.  Look in the Output window for the exact error message.  Do avoid doing this the hard way when it is simple to get the same outcome without a build event.  Project > Properties > Build tab, Platform target = x86.

Comment: Platform target is already on x86. I need corflags for my issue. I tried full path to corflags.exe too. Updated question with full error message from the output window.

Comment: That is the error message you already know, we need the one before it.  This invariably works better when you show everything you see in the Output window.  And no, you do not need corflags.  Easy to see by running it without an option, you'll see that 32BITREQ is already turned on.  So turning it on again is not sensible.

Comment: Adding quotes to the path solved the build error. However i still get an exception in my application from an old oracle connector that requires 32 bit. I don't get this error when i manually run the corflags command above on the exe file.

Comment: The standard mistake is changing the solution platform.  Which has no effect whatsoever on a C# project, it uses the same build tools for any platform, the jitter sorts it out at runtime.  Unlike a C++ project.  You must use the command I documented.  Only the setting on the EXE project matters.  Change it for both the Debug and the Release configuration.

Comment: I only have 1 project. Build->General-->Platform target is set to x86 Build-->Platform = x86. The solution platform was on default any cpu. But also tested it on x86. None if this solved the error.

Answer (score 1):

> This did not solve the error I have with an oracle connection (version 9.2). My manual corflags command does solve this issue.

You need **pay attention to the path of QardPrint.exe in your command line** after you change Build->General-->Platform target is set to `x86` Build-->Platform = `x86`.

After change platform target to `x86`, the QardPrint.exe was new generated at **x86** folder:

```
$(ProjectDir)bin\x86\$(ConfigurationName)\QardPrint.exe
```

If you do not change the previous path in the command line "`$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\QardPrint.exe`", you will get that error. I got the same error with previous command line:

[image]

If I correct the path, all thing can works fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can not understand vote down, can give any explanation?

Comment: Will do some testing with this later. Not sure either why someone down voted. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @MarkBaijens, np. If this answer not help you, please let me know for free, I will keep follow.

Comment: Well it did resolve the error visual studio was giving. But still have to manually run the corflags command for my application to work. Looks like the command is not executed well.

Comment: @MarkBaijens, according to the official documents:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool. To run the tool, use the Developer Command Prompt. It seems we have to run the corflags command on visual studio console. That is the reason why the command does not work in Visual Studio.

Comment: I see, so it's not possible to run it automatically after the build completed?

Comment: @MarkBaijens, what I think of is that create a bat file call Developer Command Prompt to run that command line. The scripts in the bat file should be ""call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
echo call corflags.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\corflags.exe" "C:\Users\Admin\Source\repos\QardPrint\QardPrint\bin\x86\Debug\QardPrint.exe" /32BITREQ+ 
The path of QardPrint.exe should be fully path. and the command in the post-build event should be: call "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.bat". You can try it.

Comment: If above method still not work, I`m afraid it's not possible to run it automatically after the build completed.